# Large dataset 2d contour plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, interpolation, contour

**Question:** What is the best way to interpolate and plot a large set of scattered data?

I have a set of scattered data with about 55,000 points. I want to make a map of these points similar to the answer provided here: [Python : 2d contour plot from 3 lists : x, y and rho?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9008370/python-2d-contour-plot-from-3-lists-x-y-and-rho).

- I implemented the code provided in that link, however I do not think that rbf interpolation is right for the job. If it is right for the job I don't know how to only include nearby points in the interpolation.
- I also tried to implement some other techniques such as SmoothBivariateSpline but I could not get the code to work. I also tried to use RectBivariateSpline (suggested here: [SciPy interpolation of large matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5328128/scipy-interpolation-of-large-matrix)) but was unable to order my data points correctly.
- I have also read about IDW (from this answer: [Inverse Distance Weighted (IDW) Interpolation with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3104781/inverse-distance-weighted-idw-interpolation-with-python)) but am unsure if it suits my needs.

I am sure there is a better method out there to interpolate the data, but I am not knowledgable about the subject. I also am not sure how to graphically represent the 55,000 points without the plot looking crazy. 
I have a plot to show what I am dealing with but I cannot post an image yet since I am new to the stack.

Comment: Do you need to interpolate or only to plot ? In the latter case you could try *tricontour* http://matplotlib.org/dev/api/axes_api.html?highlight=tricontou#matplotlib.axes.Axes.tricontour

Comment: As this stands, this question is too broad to be answerable and will probably get closed as 'off-topic - too broad' or 'off-topic - opinion based'.  If you can make simple example we might be able to help you with your second bullet point.  I would also try just binning your data down to a grid (the value of each gridbox is the average of the points that fall into it).